# Сборщик web-проектов без Node.js

Tags: веб-программирование, сборка

Ищу сборщик проектов, который будет минимизировать js, css, в идеале и изображения. Нагуглил Gulp, но он работает с Node.js. Страницы которые нужно оптимизировать - простые одностраничники,в день таких приходится "собирать" 5-10 штук и для каждой запускать npm как по мне не очень рационально. Есть ли программы для Windows подобные Gulp?

Comment: Поясните пожалуйста, почему gulp + плагины использовать нерационально?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian процесс установки всех плагинов в папку с проектом по времени аналогичен минифицированию онлайн-сервисами 1 css, 1 js и 1-2 картинок. Есть конечно вариант поставить gulp и плагины в одно место, и менять исходники на свои, собирать и копировать папку build для загрузки на сервер. Но на сколько я понимаю так никто не делает...

Comment: Ничего не мешает установить один раз в отдельную папку набор инструментов, и далее использовать их через командную строку. Например можно установить глобально `npm install clean-css` и далее из командной строки запускать для нужных файлов: `cleancss your.css`

Comment: @VladimirGamalian их же тогда надо ставить глобально с ключом -g?

Comment: Верно, забыл ключ дописать. Но также можно и локально, в какую-то отдельную директорию, откуда будете использовать (либо дописав в PATH, либо с установкой текущей директории/указанием полных путей).

Comment: @VladimirGamalian спасибо, пока попробую так